# Rails: Display database query on HTML page, ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to create a search form for my rails app, the user enters a query and based off that query, I want them to see a list of links associated with that query (these links come from my 'links' table). I created the HTML form and it has the user enter a query. I use this query

```
<%= form_tag links_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In my controller for the links table, I have an `if` statement that checks what the user has entered and it assigns `Link.where('title LIKE ?', '%{#params[:search]}%')`  to `@links`. and then converts it to an array (`.to_a`)

Here is the statement in the index action:

```
def index
  @links = Link.all
  if params[:search]
    #@links = Link.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', '%{#params[:search]}%'])
    @links = Link.where('title LIKE ?', '%{#params[:search]}%')
    @links.to_a
  end
```

`end`

In my `index.html.erb` I would like to display the result. I used `<%= @links %>` however, it displays the ActiveRecord: `#<Link::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000d5c69f0>`

How could I convert the query result ActiveRecord into an array, so then I could be able to index it?
Thanks.

Comment: use double quotes to interpolate `"%#{params[:search]}%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assigns @links like this:

```
@links = @links.to_a
```

By the way, if you want render link one-by-one using something like *@links.each*, you do not need to convert @links to array.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't EVER EVER EVER EVER use**

```
@links = Link.where('title LIKE ?', '%{#params[:search]}%')
```

this is a security issue. Check http://railscasts.com/episodes/25-sql-injection.

In order to see all likes as an output just simply do

```
@links = Link.where('title LIKE ?', params[:search]')
```

and in Views do

```
<%= @links.to_a %>
```

That should help :)